# Como descobrir qual linha está algum dado do CSV

Tags: php, csv

Boa tarde, estou com um problema que não sei como resolvo, provavelmente vai ser em PHP mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isto. Mais precisamente o que eu preciso fazer é: Tenho um site, e nele vou criar uma página separada, nessa página separada o usuário irá colocar o CPF dele, aí após colocar o CPF o sistema tem que identificar qual o nome dele e gerar uma credencial para ele poder imprimir ... Alguém te alguma ideia de como eu vou saber o nome da pessoa utilizando apenas a busca do CPF dela no CSV ?

- Não estou com o CSV aqui, mas é separado assim: NOME, IDADE, CPF, PROFISSÃO *

Comment: Ajudaria se colocasses um exemplo com poucas linhas do formato desse csv

Comment: @Miguel Completei a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte:

```
$CPF_user = $_POST['CPF']; // receber cpf do user
$lines = file('file.csv'); // array com as linhas do file.csv
foreach($lines as $l) { // percorrer as linhas
    $params = explode(',', $l); // dividir linha pelo separador de colunas
    if($params[2] == $CPF_user) {
        $name_user = $params[0]; // caso seja encontrado o $name_user fica definido
        break; // escusado continuar a percorrer as linhas
    }
}
if(isset($name_user)) {
    // encontrado
}
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado !!

Comment: @PabloAbreu de nada, ainda bem que resolveu